# Cannot upload images to Expression Engine using assets

Tags: assets, uploads

I'm getting the error :

```
Could not upload the file - server returned an unexpected response. Please check the server settings.
```

Now I've checked numerous posts already to try and solve it, I've checked double checked and triple checked the permissions. The assets path is seemingly correct as well. So I'm not too sure on what to do next.

Any help or guidance is appreciated.

Comment: Where exactly are you getting this error? In your developer console in your browser? As a pop-up from the Assets modal window?

Comment: I get this when I go to upload images in my templates. @jrothafer

Comment: Yes, I understand that, again, **where**? Are you redirected to an error page? Is it a popup that keeps you in state of an Assets modal? Details man! I need details! When in doubt, screenshot that sucker for me.

Comment: Sorry, I misunderstood you. It's a popup that appears. The image starts uploading and as soon as the progress bar reaches the end I get that popup. @jrothafer